# Find path for local video in Xcode Project

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsbundle

I need to play locally stored Videos in my iOS app.

The videos are located in the directory: `App/Resources/Videos/`

When I try to get the path with:

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myFile", ofType: "mp4", inDirectory: "App/Resources/Videos/")
```

I get nil. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved: the error was I didn't add the Target-Membership for the Videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and remove inDirectory from the function call. Just search for your file in your app main bundle.It shall do the job for you.

Comment: Thanks, I removed the `inDirectory` but the error was something else. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5.4**

```
Bundle.main.path(forResource: VideoHelper.vName, ofType: VideoHelper.vExtension)
```